# What should I do about 404 errors?

Tags: javascript, rest

So lets say for example that a book has several categories it fits in: Fiction and Thriller.

But the categories of the book are not a required field, so we get in frontend books that also don't have any categories yet set, so the server will return a 404 error for the request that gets the book categories. Is it ok to have those 404 errors appear in the console or should I do something about it?

If I'm using the fetch method from javascript, then the application will continue its course even with the 404 errors which is what I would want, but they still appear in the console, which with my current knowledge I wouldn't want.

Comment: Why can't your server return a 200 but empty result instead of a 404?

Comment: Is there a rule for what result I should return on no data found?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it ok to have 404 errors appear"? Are you asking from a cybersecurity perspective?

Comment: @AlinCatalin A 404 response code means that the resource doesn't exist. In this case, the resource exists, it just happens to be an empty set (think `null` vs an empty array). If you're also in control of the server code I would change it to give a 200 with a body of `[]` (for JSON).

Comment: What I mean by that is that I would think that if everything works as expected, I should have no errors. So a no content status code would be perfect for that.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several "not found" scenarios you need to cover here:

1. The category exists and has entries = Status 200 + array of entries
2. The category exists and has no entries = Status 200 + empty array
3. The category does not exist = Status 404

For example, in your case requests to both `/fiction` and `/thriller` should return 200, but `/slash_fiction` should return 404.

Likewise `/book/NNNN/categories` can return 200 + empty array if the book exists but has no categories, or 404 if the book does not exist.

In other words, reserve 404 for *specific situations in which the request does not reference any known entities*.